# Crossbrowser printview

Tags: c#, javascript, html, css, printing

I'm creating a printview of dynamically created content in HTML (PDF is not an option). This content covers the whole page and should be as big as possible (so sizing it down is not an option either).

Now the problem is that every browser cuts off a part of the page on the right hand side, where the size of the cut off area seems to **depend on the browser and on the size of the window**.

So it appears that any full-width content i try to print is cut off at the right hand side - differing from browser to browser, which makes it hard to adjust the page to fit since i want to keep it as big as possible.

This seems very much like a common issue, but i couldn't find a common solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can solve your problem with a print style sheet.
Here's a little article about how to use it: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/24/how-to-set-up-a-print-style-sheet/

Answer (score 0):

Ok This is what I did. I am not sure if it would help you or not but just a suggestion.

```
 @media print
{
    #wrapper{width:650px !important;}
    #form1{width:650px !important;}
    #main{width:650px !important;}
}
@media only screen {
    #wrapper{Whatever styling you have}
    #form1{Whatever styling you have}
    #main{Whatever styling you have}
}
```

Important point: media only screen I have set width mostly 100%. Works cross browser.